# Reducing n-set of vertices to rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, topology

I'm attempting to reduce a set of *n* vertices to *m* number of rectangles (points are not on a grid, and are user defined).

The easiest case is to check for 4 nodes, and confirm there's less than 3 unique distances, which would result in 1 rectangle shape. However, I was hoping to reduce *n* number of vertices into multiple rectangles, given that each subset of vertices form a rectangle. I'm happy for rectangles to be diagonal, and don't mind if it's only an approximation of a rectangle (e.g. it hangs over a vertex to make a rectangle). I'm also happy for the shapes to overlap.

Current input is user-defined:

- User clicks to place 'node', nodes can be connected to create 'edges' (max 2 node per edge, but multiple edges per node).
- Each 'edge' of a node has a start and end position (the two nodes that create it)
- User clicks can be non-grid, or on a grid (grid size is user defined, so no flood fill algorithms sadly)

I've determined a reasonable-ish solution:

[image]

1. Select random edge within node set
2. Use *A Star* algorithm on all edges, with the selected edge being the start and end position, but do not allow the algorithm to traverse that edge in the 1st instance
3. If there's a path back to the edge, we've found a closed shape
4. *String pull* the resultant path (i.e. simplify path, removing nodes/edges that are on the same line to reduce path count)
5. Do validity checks for rectangle e.g. no more than 3 unique distances
6. Repeat process for any nodes that weren't included in that path

Unfortunately, this will be fairly computationally expensive for my application, and I was hoping to do this in runtime. Does anyone have any suggestions to improve the above method, or know of another method that would be better for this?

Comment: Is the user somehow forced to create a [planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)? Are the 'edges' that the user adds always vertical/horizontal or can they be at any angle?

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, essentially. Although not all nodes are connected to one another. Edges can be at any angle

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should have phrased that differently. Are the rectangles always axis-aligned, or can they be rotated?

Comment: Sorry, I probably read that incorrectly! No, the rectangles can be rotated, they're not always axis-aligned

Comment: What the code should look for is two edges starting from some node (A) that are 90 degrees apart (connected to nodes B and C). Those two edges uniquely define a potential rectangle. The code simply has to check whether edges B,D and C,D exist (D being the node at the fourth corner of the rectangle).